# Aviarc Debug command not working?

Tags: aviarc

I've been trying to send some strings out to a file somewhere to help with testing, by doing something like:

```
<debug text="This is a test"/>
```

But I can't find where it outputs to. I've been looking in the aviarc-server.[date].log file, not sure where else it would go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  command outputs at INFO level - what is your log level set to? You can change the log level setting in the Admin application under Server Configuration. It is set to WARN by default. You can also use the Realtime Log feature from the Admin app to see *tail* the log within the browser.